# Access JSON Object using for loop

Tags: angularjs, json

This is my simplified JSON file content:

```
{
    "array": {
        "Table1": [
            {
                "h1": 0,
                "h2": 1069
            },
            {
                "h1": 587,
                "h2": 947
            }
        ],
        "Table2": [
            {
                "h1": 13,
                "h2": 0
            },
            {
                "h1": 30,
                "h2": 0
            },
            {
                "h1": 75,
                "h2": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what my console output after Angular $http call

```
var data = response.data;
$log.log(data); //Object
$log.log(data.Table1); //Array
$log.log(data.Table1[0]); //Object
$log.log(data.Table1[1].h1); //587
```

I tried below code but failed to get the value. Please help.

```
for(var a in data){ //this one correctly loops 2 times
   for(var d in a){ //I have problem with this one
     $log.log(d.h1);
   }
}
```

Comment: guess it should be ... `for(var d in data[a]){ `...

Comment: This is not JSON, it is just an Object.

Comment: change your line to this..  it will work  `for(var d in data[a])`  because you are calling inner object.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks guys.. I will accept after 7 minutes.. (SO limitation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (var a in data)` a would be the key, so `Table1` or `Table2`. The actual value is in data[a].
Also you can not traverse an Array with `for (var i in xx)` method, as far as I know

```
for(var a in data){ //this one correctly loops 2 times
   for(var d = 0; d < data[a].length; d++){
     $log.log(data[a][d].h1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in below way:-

```
 $data = file_get_contents('your json data is here.json');
 $content = json_decode($data); 
 foreach($content as $row){
    foreach($row as $data_array){
      foreach($data_array as $item){
       echo 'H1 data item - '.$item->h1;
       echo '    H2 data item - '.$item->h2.'<br>';
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be using `data[a]` to get inner object. Basically you would be accessing object by its `key`

```
for(var a in data){
   for(var d in data[a]){ 
     $log.log(d.h1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have problems with nesting. Your structure is data -> array -> table -> h1. Second, ther for-in construction iterates by the key. So, the a variable in construction for(var i in myArr) refers to the element key, not to the object in array. So, the whole construction in your case may look like this

```
for(var a in data.array){
   for(var d in data.array[a]){
     console.log(data.array[a][d].h1);
   }
}
```

P.S. have a look at [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.